# Do units gain exp while on dispatch missions?

Tags: final-fantasy-tactics-advance

I understand they get ability points, but do they gain experience as well?

Comment: Ah FFTA, amazing game! I believe not but will give you a definitive answer later., when I know. enjoy! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From what I've noticed, experience is only gained during battle after each turn. Have never had a unit level up during a dispatch mission.